# How to display only certain rows from a column in database in MVC?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3, model-view-controller

Suppose I have a Table name AutoPurge with 2 columns ID (identity) and Parameter. 
There are 4 records in this table - a, b, c and d.

Assume, I wish to display this 4 value in a table format in an MVC application. So I pass this following code to the view from my controller.

```
        //AutoPurge is table
        return View(await _context.AutoPurge.ToListAsync());
```

So by right, this will display all 4 values (a, b, c and d described above) in a table format in my View. 
If i only want to display all the rows (a, b, c) except the row "d", may I ask how can i code for this?

Answer (score 1):

This can be done by applying a predicate to your query, very much like you would do in SQL:

```
var result = await _context.AutoPurge.Where(x => x.Id != "d").ToListAsync();
return View(result);
```

You have to change that predicate to your definition, since I don't know how you want to filter specifically.

Answer (score 0):

Execute query excluding that specific value i.e.: `SELECT * FROM AutoPurge A WHERE A.Parameter NOT IN ('d')` or filter the ArrayList after returning all the records using C#.
`new ArrayList(CompleteList.Cast<List>().Where(d => d.VID != "d").ToList());`

Hope it will work.